# How to make a side-scrolling website with a responsive layout...?

Tags: jquery, scroll, responsive-design

I'd like my site content to be side-scrolling. In other words, I when a link is clicked, I want that page to "scroll into" the viewport from the side.

Much like this page: http://s3.sitepoint.com/examples/sidescroll/demo4.html

However, I'd also like the content of each "page" (or div) to be responsive and fit the viewport. In the demo, when the page is sized down, the text gets cut-off (among other things).

I was planning on making a really wide div and using JQuery animation to scroll to various points, but if there's a better way, please let me know. Also, I was planning on setting the wrapper overflow to "hidden", so as to disable the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery mobile has the features you need out of the box. It has sort of side-scrolling features and uses ajax extensively. How ever if you are targeting desktop as well it might be not the exact but it might work for you. It has great support for responsive design . http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, my primary target is desktop users.